# Как вычислить размер ячейки CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

У меня есть CollectionView. В одной из ячеек этого CollectionView(1) содержится другой CollectionView(2). Возникла проблема, если во втором CollectionView(2) много элементов, то происходит скроллинг не основного CollectionView(1), а того, который содержится в ячейке.

На сколько я понял, необходимо вычислить размер всех ячеек CollectionView(2) и задать высоту ячейки CollectionView(1) равную этому размеру(чтобы CollectionView(2) растянулся и не скролился, т.к. он имеет достаточную высоту).

Правильно ли я додумался? Существуют ли готовые решения моей проблемы?

Comment: Почему не разделить на секции и выводить ячейки другого типа в другой секции, если для второй CollectionView все-равно не нужен скролл?

Comment: Спасибо, то что мне нужно!